# Diagnosing intermittent 404 through a firewall, VersionInvalid, "Request may not be compliant with HTTP/1.1. "

Tags: windows, iis, http.sys

I have software running on a machine that is getting intermittent 404 responses when calling a Rest API.

The IIS logs do not show the 404 being returned, however the HTTPERR log file does, so I understand this to be a problem with HTTP.SYS before it would pass the request on to IIS.

The HTTPERR log shows:

```
2023-07-27 09:38:49 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX XXXXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 80 - PROXY TCP4 - 400 - BadRequest -
```

Generating a trace file shows additional information about the problem.

```
Opcode: ParseRequestFailed  
Reason: VersionInvalid
Message: Parsing of request (request ID 17293822575545184345) failed due to reason: VersionInvalid. Request may not be compliant with HTTP/1.1.
```

I'm now uncertain of how to proceed.

- I don't think attaching Fiddler to watch the client traffic is going to be helpful, there is a proxy involved and I'll see traffic coming out of the client to the proxy and not what the proxy is sending to the server.  The client is used on a lot of systems without issue.  Am I correct in this assumption?
- I think that I need to see the actual traffic going into the web server, but I'm not sure I want to attach something to intercept all the traffic as it's a production machine (and only a production machine) that has this issue.  Is there another way to see the body of the message that is causing the problem?
- What is the HTTPERR log showing when it says "PROXY TCP4"?  Is this a part of the body of the request that is coming in?

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.